# Working with html5 canvas using images from localhost and s3

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, amazon-s3

Currently I try to solve CORS-problem for using images from localserver (replaced to box.dev in hosts) and from S3 to combine them in canvas.
I have read few links how to solve this problem and tried all them, but still receive error:

"Access to Image at 'https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/x/y/z/image.jpg' from origin 'http://box.dev:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://box.dev:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I use 'Anonymous' value for crossOrigin attribute for image:

```
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'Anonymous');
```

Currently in S3 I have next CORS-configuration XML:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Is there I have something missing?
Thank you!